# Missing argument for parameter #1 in call when setting initial value

Tags: swift, ios8, realm

I'm trying to set current locale country as initial value:

```
class Location: RLMObject {
    dynamic var country = currentCountry()

    func currentCountry() -> String!{
        let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        let countryCode = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as String

        let countryName = locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode, value: countryCode)
        return countryName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that country is an *instance* variable and currentCountry is an *instance* function as well. When you want to initialize country, there is no instance yet, so you cannot reference the currentCountry function. But if you change like:

```
dynamic var country = YOUR_CLASS_NAME.currentCountry()

class func currentCountry() -> String!{
    let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    let countryCode = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as String

    let countryName = locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode, value: countryCode)
    return countryName
}
```

it will work,  beacuse now currentCountry is a *class* function, and that is available at initialization.

Or if you don't want to define an explicit function for that, just use a closure for the computed property syntax:

```
dynamic var country: String {
    let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    let countryCode = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as String

    let countryName = locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode, value: countryCode)
    return countryName!
}
```

Or the third option, if you want the keep your function, you have to set the county variable after the initialization, like:

```
dynamic var country: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    country = currentCountry()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bug with `Xcode Simulator iOS 8.1`.

It returns `nil` for `locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode, value: countryCode)`