# How to find value of UIImage called in ViewDidLoad, pass to another function in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am using a simple function to call a random image when a view controller is loaded.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var randomtest = ReturnRandom()
    mainImage.image = UIImage(named: randomtest)
}
```

I want a button's action to be based on what image was displayed. For example

```
@IBAction func Button1(sender: AnyObject) { 
switch randomtest {
case 1: //Do something here
case 2: //Do something different here
default:  
}
```

However I can not figure out how to get the value of "randomtest" out of ViewDidLoad.  I also can not seem to create the random number outside the ViewDidLoad then pass the variable in.  Sorry I'm new to all this, iOS development is a long way away from php...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I was having trouble declaring the result of my function as a instance variable is that my function is also an **instance function**. I can not call it, there has been no instance.  So this

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

var randomtest: Int = ReturnRandom();
```

Will return a "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call" 
For more details please check out this very helpful thread [on setting initial values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544642/missing-argument-for-parameter-1-in-call-when-setting-initial-value). Since my function was so simple I just computed the property while setting the initial value, no need for an additional class level function.

```
dynamic var randomtest:String {
let imageNumber = arc4random_uniform(3)
var imageString = String(imageNumber)
return (imageString)}
```

Hope this helps someone.